# SSRS 2017 - Can't Go to Next Page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I am viewing a report deployed to my SSRS 2017 report server. When the report runs, it show 0/0 pages and clicking on the next page button does nothing. When I export the report to PDF I get 129 pages. If I use the search box to look for text within the report, then it shows pages "0/2 ?" and I use the next page button.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: have you unchecked the "keep together" property .. just a thought !

Comment: Maybe you have set InteractiveSize height to 0 (show everything in one page on report viewer). Change these values to match your page size if you want report view to match PDF size

Comment: I have tried both of those properties and it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Try to add a rectangle and under propertys check `Add page break after` and look at the behaviour again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by having read committed snapshot isolation set to "on" in the report server databases.